# how to change the master database collation in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

is there any way to change the master database collation in MsSql server 2008 to another collation, instead of reinstall it  ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[You need to rebuild/recreate the master database as described here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179254.aspx)

(Though that article also goes through the steps to change all user databases to the new collation you probably just need to [follow the steps here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207003.aspx))